# How to get the latest file with os.system using scp in python?

Tags: python, scp, os.system

I want to use python **os.system** library to get/scp the latest folder from a remote remote UNIX directory, which is a folder system with names including datetime such as :

```
[usr1@server1 stats_from_dir]$ pwd
/tmp/dir1/stats_from_dir

[usr1@server1 stats_from_dir]$ ls -alrth
drwxr-x---  2  23K Aug 28 12:50 pmexport_20200825
drwxr-x---  2  23K Aug 28 12:50 pmexport_20200826
drwxr-x---  2  21K Aug 28 12:50 pmexport_20200827
```

I can get all the folders like this ;

```
import os
    
get_files = 'scp -r usr1@10.1.1.39:/tmp/dir1/stats_from_dir/* /dir2/.'
    
os.system(get_files)
```

But how can I get only latest folder? Is there any way to do this within os.system library with paramters without using other libraries such as paramiko, subprocess ..etc ?

Comment: Why would you do this with `os.system()` instead of a library like paramiko?

Comment: installation of any other library is limited..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
import os
    
get_files = "scp -r usr1@10.1.1.39:/tmp/dir1/stats_from_dir/$(ssh usr1@10.1.1.39 'ls -t /tmp/dir1/stats_from_dir/ | head -1') /dir2/."
    
os.system(get_files)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the actual date of the folder?

**Assuming the last folder is yesterday**

Then compile yesterday's date with datetime.date and subtract one day by using datetime.timedelta

Then turn yesterday in the string format you need with strftime.

Last, append that day to your string for which you use os.system.

```
import os
import datetime
    

yesterday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
yesterday_string = yesterday.strftime('%Y%m%d')

get_files = 'scp -r usr1@10.1.1.39:/tmp/dir1/stats_from_dir/pmexport_{} /dir2/.'.format(yesterday_string)
    
os.system(get_files)
```